# mysql Any duplicate of two fields

Tags: mysql

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJBYh.png)

[filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D0PJ.png)

I want userid = 1 or object = 1. Imagine that there are only three pieces of data that are not repeated, tried many methods， but they will always be repeated

I want to take the data with userid or object 1, but don't repeat it.

**If userid=1 and object = 2, don't the data with object=1 and userId=2. If object=1 and userId=2, don't use the data with userid=1 and object = 1**

```sql
select userId, object from userChat where (userId = 1 or object = 1) group by userId, object;
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Can you please explain more..
what is the repeated values?
Perhaps your base data of information is incorrect.
Before using the `group by`, try to query the data and retrieve the information you need, then, if needed use the `group by` .

Following your explanation, Just write it as you say it...

```
   select userId, object 
    from userChat 
    where (userId = 1 and object <> 1) or (object=1 and userId<>1)
```

Comment: so sorry  I want to take the data with userid or object 1, but don't repeat it. If userid=1, don't use the data with object=1. If object=1, don't use the data with userid=1

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way. First, find out the set of two groups of data and intersect them, that is, there is no duplicate data result.
It feels amazing

```sql
select id from
(
    select object as id from userChat where (userId = 1)
    union all
    select userId as id from userChat where (object = 1)
) t
group by id order by id;
```